# Persist data through application restart but not reboot

Tags: c#, persistence, volatile, memory-mapped-files

Is there a convenient mechanism that will allow me to persist information that will survive across application restarts but not system reboots?

At the most blunt end of the spectrum, I know I can create a Ramdisk and use that, but it seems very inelegant.

I was hoping I could use a memory-mapped file without disk backing, however, that seems to be cleaned up as soon as there are no processes with an open handle.

I could have a second process purely to keep a handle open but again, that's pretty inelegant. Also, I want this to work across debugging sessions and would rather not juggle running processes with locked binaries on disk.

Is there a clean way to do this? Can I flag a memory-mapped file as long-lived?

Comment: Is it elegant enough to clear persistent file on every OS startup?

Comment: If that's the only option, so be it, but what mechanism are you considering? I wouldn't want to wait until app start, so perhaps a scheduled task? But then I have to clean _that_ up when I'm uninstalling. It also means dropping clutter eg in AppData. It's all doable but surely there must be _some_ semi-volatile storage area in windows I can access via code?

Comment: [Data Storage with PersistentDictionary](https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/master/Documentation/PersistentDictionaryDocumentation.md). Based on [ESENT](https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/master/Documentation/ManagedEsentDocumentation.md) (Windows native). The dictionary can be flushed to disk, if necessary.